# Getting Facebook profile pic from user (via Graph) - detect if it's a blank (i.e. default) image?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch the profile pics of the people commenting on a client's Facebook page, so they can be displayed on the website, etc.

I'm getting the user IDs via the `/[page_name]/feed/` graph call and I'm putting that into a URL form like so:

```
$id = $item['from']['id'];
$link = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$id}/picture?type=large";
```

It's working well - I'm getting a number of profile pictures back, however some look like this: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/yDnr5YfbJCH.gif

I want to only show real profile pics - is there a way of detecting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is doable, but will need file comparison.
Facebook uses 2 images as default avatars, 1 for males, another for females.
So, you will have to compare the image that you get with one of these.

A simple comparison would be to compare both of them after converting their bytes to strings.
Simplest example :

```
<?php

$photo1 = "http://graph.facebook.com/2131243434/picture?type=large";
$photo2 = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yL/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif";
if (md5(file_get_contents($photo1)) ==  md5(file_get_contents($photo2))) {
       echo "NO PICTURE";
}
 else {
echo "REAL PICTURE";
}


?>
```

That would be a slow operation, so you can put it as a cron job to verify images at backend.
You can optimize it a little bit by storing the md5 of default avatar in db, so only 1 URL needs to be fetched for comparison.

This can be made CHANGE PROOF, use a graph api url which is sure to return default avatar, then you dont have to worry about change in default avatar image , you just have to compare 2 graph api URLS.
eg. compare :
a ) `http://graph.facebook.com/MY_TEST_ID/picture?type=large` ( this always returns default avatar)
b) `http://graph.facebook.com/MY_NEW_USER_ID/picture?type=large` ( the user I want to test)

Comment: Hm, was hoping that Facebook might have an flag I could pass that would give me a 404 instead of a holding image. I'll wait a little while and if nobody else comes up with another solution, will accept yours. Tis a good solution just not as elegant as I'd have liked (what if they change their default image in future, etc). Thanks though :-)

Comment: This can be made CHANGE PROOF, use a graph api url which is sure to return default avatar, then you dont have to worry about change in default avatar image , you just have to compare 2 graph api URLS

Comment: While this approach may work, it is hackish and not necessary. See my answer below for a description of how to do this correctly, using the `is_silhouette` value that Graph provides

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer, @MattRabe's answer is a better approach.

Answer (score 25):

The Graph API does include a flag that allows you to detect whether or not a user's facebook avatar is the default one...

You can accomplish this by appending `&redirect=false` to the end of your Graph image URL.

For example:

A normal image url such as

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[USERNAME]/picture?type=large
```

will redirect to an actual image file, giving the impression of returning an actual image.
But a url such as

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[USERNAME]/picture?type=large&redirect=false
```

will return JSON - something like:

```
{"data": {
    "url": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/623549_1210877749_349605729_n.jpg",
    "is_silhouette": false
}}
```

(source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

**UPDATE:**
URI has changed: `type=large` no longer works, you must now specify explicit width/height like so:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[USERNAME]/picture?width=200&height=600
```

Note the `"is_silhouette"` attribute - it will be `true` or `false`.  If `true`, the user's facebook image is a *default* image.

Making this judgement on an "inline" basis will require cURL, and you could integrate it with your code something like this:

```
// Setup
$id = $item['from']['id'];
$link = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$id}/picture?type=large";

// Get avatar info from FB via cURL
$url = $link. "&redirect=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$avatarInfo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

// Process cURL response
$isDefaultAvatar = false;
if ($avatarInfo)
{
    $avatarInfo = json_decode($avatarInfo);
    if (isset($avatarInfo->data->is_silhouette) && $avatarInfo->data->is_silhouette) $isDefaultAvatar = true;
}

// Output
echo "This " .($isDefaultAvatar ? "IS" : "IS NOT"). " a default avatar.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash the default image, store the hash for default male/female, compare?

Comment: Sounds like I might have to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already making a call to the Graph API to get user data like the avatar, don't make an additional API call to `/picture` like suggested above.

Just include `picture` in the [fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fields) param when you make your first call to Graph API, then the response will include the `is_silhouette` offset, if it's set to true the user has the default avatar.

Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?access_token=[token]&fields=name,picture
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": "100103095474350",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "is_silhouette": true,
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/...jpg"
        }
    }
}
```