# How do I know if the event has a custom profile picture or just the default picture through Open Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Facebook profile pic from user (via Graph) - detect if it's a blank (i.e. default) image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984041/getting-facebook-profile-pic-from-user-via-graph-detect-if-its-a-blank-i-e)

As on facebook site, it will display the creator's the picture if the event does not have a custom profile picture, I want to know if there is a flag to indicate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no flag to indicate this. `/eventid/picture` just returns the URL, no flags. For more information http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: I know it, the problem is that even the event does not have a user uploaded picture, the above API will also return an URL. And that URL is a CDN url with random filename so it's no certain way to know if it is default picture or not.

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984041/getting-facebook-profile-pic-from-user-via-graph-detect-if-its-a-blank-i-e/7984093#7984093